# How do I fix this output problem with my (), [], {} checker?

Tags: java

The problem is after scanning the file called "confused.dat" it outputs 90% of what it is supposed to and the other 10% are incorrect.

I have tried exchanging methods of scanning the file but nothing really changed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class confused {
    public static boolean isBalanced(String inp) {
        if ((inp.length() % 2) == 1){ return false;}
            else {
                Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
                    for (char brackBrick : inp.toCharArray())
                        switch (brackBrick) {
                            case '{': s.push('}'); break;
                            case '(': s.push(')'); break;
                            case '[': s.push(']'); break;
                            default : if (s.isEmpty() || brackBrick != s.peek()) { return false;}
                                      s.pop();
                }
            return s.isEmpty();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) /*throws FileNotFoundException*/ {

      try{
          Scanner scrn = new Scanner (new File("confused.dat"));
          while (scrn.hasNextLine()){
              boolean answer = isBalanced(scrn.nextLine());

              if (answer) {
                  System.out.println("Yes");
              } else {
                  System.out.println("No");
              }
          }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }
}
```

confused.dat file:

```
([])
(([()])))
([()[]()])()
(([()])
([] )
(([()])))
([()[]()])()
(
(]
)(
][
```

Here is expected output vs. the actual output

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mLVp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I think I got it. You were actually pretty close. First off, drop this line

```
if ((inp.length() % 2) == 1){ return false;}
```

and then ignore empty spaces by adding the following condition in your `switch` statement:

```
case ' ': break;
```

So all in all the updated method now looks like this

```
public static boolean isBalanced(String inp) {
    Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
    for (char brackBrick : inp.toCharArray()) {
        switch (brackBrick) {
            case '{': s.push('}'); break;
            case '(': s.push(')'); break;
            case '[': s.push(']'); break;
            case ' ': break;
            default : if (s.isEmpty() || brackBrick != s.peek()) { return false;}
                s.pop();
        }
    }

    return s.isEmpty();
}
```

You should now get the following output

```
Yes
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes
No
No
No
No
```

Comment: Thankyou very much my good man, I currently finishing my final for my Advanced Computer Science class and have one more program to finish thanks to your help!

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

shouldn't it be a no, because

```
if ((inp.length() % 2) == 1){ return false;}

if (answer) {
              System.out.println("Yes");
          } else {
              System.out.println("No");
```

(([()]))) is not a even number, so therefore it false, and thus will print no.

Comment: nope its supposed to be a yes due to (([()]))) having uneven amount of parenthesis

Comment: @MultostheLad But isn't it checking if it is even? (([()]))) is an uneven length, and `"(([()])))".length() % 2 == 1`, thus it will return false, printing no